# Adding password protect website in React Js

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a password protect using htaccess for my local react app but it's not working. I placed my password file in the root folder.

.htaccess

```
AuthType Basic 
AuthName "My Protected Folder" 
AuthUserFile /.htpassword 
require valid-user
```

.htpassword

```
test:{SHA}qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=
```

The login should be `test` for both username and password. Here is the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-field-rw5i4

I'm not very sure if it's working that way with react but tried it with php language (wampserver) and it works fine.

Comment: you need apache for this to work

Comment: @DerekPollard I see. Didn't have any idea that it needs apache to work it out. By the way thank you.